# What desktop boards support VT-D or IOMMU?

Tags: virtualization, motherboard

I'm looking for a desktop board that supports either VT-D (Intel) or IOMMU (AMD) technology.  This is the IO virtualization technology, not VT-x for CPU virtualization.  I've found a list of chipsets that are purported to have this, but every board I look at, the vendor has decided to not support that feature.  I would really prefer a desktop board over a server board for this.

Does anyone have a specific model that is known to support this technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at http://wiki.xensource.com/xenwiki/VTdHowTo , consumer boards are hit and miss but server boards are always work. I would use the parts recommended here napp-it.org/napp-it/all-in-one/index_en.html. The Supermicro X8SIL-F is a good choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are currently 6 desktop boards that support VT-d listed by Intel:

http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-030922.htm

Answer (score 1):

Support of the board is not fully accurate information, VT-d is about [CPU](http://ark.intel.com/search/advanced?VTD=true) (beware of stepping C1), [chipset](http://www.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/CS-030922.htm) (as Michal linked), BIOS (many times it depends on CMOS Setup choice), OS (in case of linux you should have proper kernel modules) and VM solution.

Answer (score 0):

My board has the feature. Never tried virtualization, so I cannot give you feedback on how it performs in practice, but I am absolutely sure you can enable it (just checked the user guide and yes it has a BIOS item for enabling VT-d). The board is the Asus P6X58D Premium, for LGA 1366 processors.